# Which system calls could create a new process?

Tags: process, embedded, fork, multithreading

When executing `ps` command in my Linux system i see some user processes twice (different PID...). I wonder if they are new processes or threads of the same process. I know some functions in standard C library that could create a new process such `fork()`. I wonder what concrete functions can make a process appear twice when i execute `ps` command because i am looking in the source code where the new process or thread is created.

Comment: Can you post output of `ps -fLa`?

Comment: my version of `ps` accepts no option (busybox ps in embedded device).

Comment: In Linux, threads are LWP (light-weight processes). Other version of *nix may be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Little bit confusing. `fork` is a system call which creates a new process by copying the parent process' image. After that if child process wants to be another program, it calls some of the `exec` family system calls, such as `execl`. If you for example want to run `ls` in shell, shell forks new child process which then calls `execl("/bin/ls")`.

If you see two programs and their `pid`'s are different, check their `ppid`'s (parent id's). For example, if `p1` is `ppid` of process whose `pid` is `p2`, it means that process whose id is `p1` forked that process. But if first process' `ppid` is not same that the other process' `pid`, it means that the same command is executed twice.

If `pid` and `ppid` are same, but `tid`'s (thread id's) are different, it means that it's one process that has 2 threads.

I think that making your own shell is a good start point.

Comment: Threads have different `PID` in my system, so it depends of C library and kernel.